# WooCommerce, WP all import - Find product ID by attribute value

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce, wpallimport

I want to update WooCommerce products by the WP All import. I have 2 independent xml files (from the first one I'm getting prices, from the second one descriptions). For some reasons product's `_sku` is `{code}` from the first one xml not `{ean}`. So I put `{ean}` into product attribute `pa_ean` to match the products from the first one and the second one xml.
Now I don't know how to write the php function to return `product_id` so WP All import could update right products with right descriptions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I put `{ean}` to Custom field, not to Attribute and after that I can easily use it in WP All import.

Answer (score 1):

Do you have any unique identifier that are same for the product in both files? Like product_key or something. If you have it you can store it as custom meta for that product and get product by that meta key, something like below  ↓

```
function check_if_product_exist($rawDataFromFile) {
        global $products;

        // Get WC_Product Objects
        $products = wc_get_products([
            'meta_key' => 'your_meta_key',
            'meta_value' => $rawDataFromFile->your_key
        ]);

        if (!empty($products)) {
            return $products[0];
        }
        return null;
    }
```

Comment: HI, thanks for reply.
I have EAN in both xmls and I'm putting it into WooCommerce product Attribute as you can see on this picture:
https://ibb.co/9sh0Jkx

Comment: Nobody will help?